# IIS Express port 80 and 443 with custom domains only some sites starts when debugging from Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

Hi i'm trying to run iis express on port 80 and 443 with custom domain names. I almost got everything working but for some reason it won't start all my sites when debugging and i can't really figure out why.

Here is my Application pools and sites from applicationhost.config

```
<applicationPools>  
        <add name="AppAdmin" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="AppAPI" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="AppMembers" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="AppNls" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="AppEvents" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="AppUserdata" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="AppWebhooks" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="AppWebb" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeLoader="v4.0">
            <processModel />
        </applicationPoolDefaults>
```

```
    <sites>
        <site name="AppAdmin" id="3" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppAdmin">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\Admin" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:admin.local.se" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:admin.local.se" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="AppAPI" id="4" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppAPI">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\API" />
            </application>
            <application path="/appdirect" applicationPool="AppAPI">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\AppSecondAPI" />
            </application>
            <application path="/magnet" applicationPool="AppAPI">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\AppWebAPI" />
            </application>
            <application path="/partner" applicationPool="AppAPI">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\AppThridAPI" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:api.local.se" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:api.local.se" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="AppMembers" id="5" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppMembers">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\Members" />
            </application>
            <application path="/dashboard" applicationPool="AppMembers">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\dashboard" />
            </application>
            <application path="/InternalAPIs" applicationPool="AppMembers">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\InternalAPIs" />
            </application>
            <application path="/FileArchive" applicationPool="AppMembers">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\FileArchive" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:members.local.se" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:members.local.se"/>
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="AppNls" id="6" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppNls">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\nls" />
            </application>
            <application path="/trchive" applicationPool="AppNls">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\nls\Archive" />
            </application>
            <application path="/cs" applicationPool="AppNls">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\nls\cs" />
            </application>
            <application path="/shared" applicationPool="AppNls">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\nls\Shared" />
            </application>
            <application path="/thumbnail" applicationPool="AppNls">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\nls\Thumbnail" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:nls.local.se" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:nls.local.se" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="AppEvents" id="7" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppEvents">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\AppEvents" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:appevent.local.se" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:appevent.local.se" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="AppWebhooks" id="9" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppWebhooks">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\Webhooks" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:webhooks.local.se" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:webhooks.local.se" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="AppUserdata" id="8" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppUserdata">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="\\networkpath\folder\UserData" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:userdata.local.se" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:userdata.local.se" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="AppWebb" id="12" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="AppWebb">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\_projects\_svn\proj\AppWebb" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:local.se" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:www.local.se" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
```

If i set AppAdmin as startup then iis express will start the following sites

- AppAdmin
- AppMembers
- AppNls
- AppEvents
- AppWebHooks

So it won't start

- AppApi
- AppUserData
- AppWebb

How does VS or IIS express choose what sites to start? I can't find anyything in *.sln or *.csproj that will give me an hint.

This is what i have done to get this far.

- Added the domains to hosts-file pointing to 127.0.0.1
- I have added all the urls with `netsh http add urlacl url=*THEURL* user=everyone`
- I run VS as Admin
- I have added the custom urls here
  [image: desc]

I have tried to set AppAdmin and AppApi as startup projects then the IIS Express just give me "Unknow error" and from what i can see nog logs anywhere.

It's always the same sites that starts, if i change the startup project to AppWebb for example then these sites start AppApi, AppUserData, AppWebb and not the ones that starts with AppAdmin as startup..

Verisions and stuff

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015
- All the projects are ASP.NET 4.5.1

Is it possible to run a setup like this?
Any help here would be nice, if something is unclear please comment and i will try to update the question.

Comment: You can use Process Explorer to analyze the arguments passed to IIS Express by Visual Studio. Generally speaking you should not put multiple sites in the configuration file. The future of deployment would be container based, and each web apps should be packaged as one site image.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. the arguments passed is what i expect: ""C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"  /config:"D:\_projects\_svn\Project\.vs\config\applicationhost.config" /site:"AppAdmin" /apppool:"AppAdmin"" 

And like that for the sites that starts. What i can't get my head around is why do they start. When i select AppAdmin as startup and press f5 debug only the five above starts. Why not all why not only AppAdmin?